# Integral of $\left(\sum\limits_n\cos\theta_n\right)^m\prod\limits_{r<s}(\cos\theta_r-\cos\theta_s)^2\prod\limits_j(1+\cos\theta_j)$ on $[0,\pi]^k$

Tags: combinatorics, definite-integrals

Prove that for positive integers $k$, $m$
$$\frac{{2^k}^{2-2k}}{\pi^k k
!}\int_{[0,\pi]^k} (2\cos\theta_1 + \cdots +2\cos\theta_k)^m
\prod_{1\leq r <s \leq k}(\cos\theta_r - \cos\theta_s)^2
\prod\limits_{i=1}^k (1+\cos\theta_i)\,d\theta_1 \ldots d\theta_k\\
= \sum\limits_{t_1+ \cdots +t_k=m}{m \choose t_1,\ldots,t_k} \det {\left({{t_i+2k-i-j}\choose {\lfloor {\frac {t_i+2k-i-j}{2}}\rfloor
}}\right)}^k_{i,j=1}$$
 I have no idea how to begin to solve this question. It would be easy for me if you give me some hints or some steps to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

Hint : the first product is the square of a Vandermonde determinant, let's name it $V(\theta)^2$. If you develop the term in $(2 \cos(\theta_1)+...+ 2 \cos(\theta_k))^m$, you get by the multinomial formula

$$\sum_{t_1+...+t_k = m} {m \choose t_1, ..., t_k} \int (2\cos(\theta_1))^{t_1}...(2\cos(\theta_{k}))^{t_k} V(\theta)^2 d\mu(\theta_1)...d\mu(\theta_k)
$$

with $\mu$ the measure whose density wrt the Lebesgue measure on $[0,\pi]$ is $1+\cos(\theta)$.

Now, there is this famous Andreief's formula (basically, it's just a generalization of Fubini-Tonnelli) which states that if $f_1, ..., f_k, g_1, ..., g_k$ are in $L^2(\mu)$, then

$$\int...\int \mathrm{det}(f_i(x_j))\mathrm{det}(g_i(x_j))\prod_{i=1}^k d\mu (x_i) = n!\cdot \mathrm{det}\left( \int...\int f_i(x) g_j(x) d\mu(x) \right) $$

(this is true for every measure $\mu$)

You want to apply this to the integrals $\int (2\cos(\theta_1))^{t_1}...(2\cos(\theta_{k}))^{t_k} V(\theta)^2 d\mu(\theta_1)...d\mu(\theta_k)$, by inserting the cosines into the corresponding rows of the Vandermonde determinant.